# VirtualBox + Tails ... types of Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox, operating-systems, tor, tails

I want to use Tails (version 3.7) on VirtualBox (version 5.2.12)

And there are a lot of types of Linux you can choose:

```
Linux x32
Linux x64
Fedora x32
Fedora x64
Ubuntu x32
Ubuntu x64
Debian x32
Debian x64
etc...
etc...
```

[image]

The question is - what type should I choose and why?

**What is the key difference between them?**

**What is the influence does chosen type of Linux bring to Tails itself?**

It bothers me, because when you launch Tails, whatever type of Linux you choose - they all look the same.

Thanks.

Comment: @dsstorefile1  yep, I know that Tails for now is x64 only. So if I choose Ubuntu x64 or Debian x64 - in Tails itself it wouldn't give anny difference?

Comment: @dsstorefile1  ok, now I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those "VM types" are just presets which are optimized for the said OS (e.g. recommended RAM, recommended disk space, etc.).

You can choose any preset you want, they all should work the same (the only thing that is really important is 32-bit/64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Tim Schumacher’s answer is correct for most use cases, but there is a little more to. So let’s elaborate a on it:

I asked myself the same question whenever I install an OS like ParrotOS, which does not have a matching type in the OS selection wizard. It could be `Debian (64-bit)`, because it‘s Debian-based, `Other Linux (64-bit)` or `Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x / 5.x (64-bit)`.

The [VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#gui-createvm) states

> Depending on your selection, Oracle VM VirtualBox will enable or disable certain VM settings that your guest OS may require.

That information is still a bit ambiguous. If you look at the [source code of VirtualBox](https://github.com/mdaniel/virtualbox-org-svn-vbox-trunk/blob/501cba451aad877b0310fd25a1eee7f3f43a83f2/src/VBox/Main/src-all/Global.cpp) though, you can see what settings are set by the different `OS types`.

For `Debian (64-bit)` the following is defined:

```
{ "Linux",   "Linux",             "Debian_64",          "Debian (64-bit)",
  VBOXOSTYPE_Debian_x64,      VBOXOSHINT_64BIT | VBOXOSHINT_HWVIRTEX | VBOXOSHINT_IOAPIC | VBOXOSHINT_RTCUTC
                            | VBOXOSHINT_USBTABLET | VBOXOSHINT_X2APIC,
  1, 1024,  16,  8 * _1G64, GraphicsControllerType_VMSVGA, NetworkAdapterType_I82540EM, 0, StorageControllerType_PIIX4, StorageBus_IDE,
  StorageControllerType_IntelAhci, StorageBus_SATA, ChipsetType_PIIX3, IommuType_None, AudioControllerType_AC97, AudioCodecType_AD1980},
```

While for `Other Linux (64-bit)` the following is defined:

```
{ "Linux",   "Linux",             "Linux_64",           "Other Linux (64-bit)",
  VBOXOSTYPE_Linux_x64,       VBOXOSHINT_64BIT | VBOXOSHINT_PAE | VBOXOSHINT_HWVIRTEX | VBOXOSHINT_IOAPIC
                            | VBOXOSHINT_RTCUTC | VBOXOSHINT_USBTABLET | VBOXOSHINT_X2APIC,
  1,  512,  16,  8 * _1G64, GraphicsControllerType_VMSVGA, NetworkAdapterType_I82540EM, 0, StorageControllerType_PIIX4, StorageBus_IDE,
  StorageControllerType_PIIX4, StorageBus_IDE, ChipsetType_PIIX3, IommuType_None, AudioControllerType_AC97, AudioCodecType_STAC9700  },
```

If you compare those two configurations, you see that the Debian template is setting different a `AudioCodecType`, `StorageControllerType` and `StorageBus`. If you compare then the configuration of `Other Linux (64-bit)` with the ones of the different Linux kernels, you see that `Other Linux` is probably set to be backwards compatible as much as possible, as it shares some of its settings with the older Linux kernel `OS type templates`.

If those settings affect you is left to your own research. Feel free to extend my answer here.

As a first step though, the [VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html) is consulted again, about the effect of the type of an `IDE controller` hardware setting:

> You can also select which exact type of IDE controller hardware Oracle VM VirtualBox should present to the virtual machine: PIIX3, PIIX4, or ICH6. This makes no difference in terms of performance, but if you import a virtual machine from another virtualization product, the OS in that machine may expect a particular controller type and crash if it is not found.

and about choosing a `SATA controller`:

> Like a real SATA controller, Oracle VM VirtualBox's virtual SATA controller operates faster and also consumes fewer CPU resources than the virtual IDE controller. Also, this enables you to connect up to 30 virtual hard disks to one machine instead of just three, when compared to the Oracle VM VirtualBox IDE controller with a DVD drive attached.

---

So to come to a conclusion, it should be safe to select either of them, unless you have knowledge that your OS requires specific hardware. Using the modern Linux kernel `OS type templates` should be a faster and less resource intensive than choosing for example `Other Linux (64-bit)`.